# Need to execute set of commands on remote machine using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sed, expect

I am trying the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

NodeIP="10.63.12.19"
userpd="password"



expect -c "
    spawn ssh root@$NodeIP
    expect "*assword:"
    send \"$userpd\r\"
    interact
    " 

CONFIG_FILE="/etc/main/params.conf"

User_val=10
IP_val=5
Blocking_max=2
Monitoring_max=2

sed -c -i "s/\(userMaxFailAttempts *= *\).*/\1$User_max/" $CONFIG_FILE
sed -c -i "s/\(userMonitoringWindow *= *\).*/\1$Monitoring_window/" $CONFIG_FILE
sed -c -i "s/\(userBlockingWindow *= *\).*/\1$Blocking_window/" $CONFIG_FILE
sed -c -i "s/\(ipMaxFailAttempts *= *\).*/\1$IP_max/" $CONFIG_FILE
sed -c -i "s/\(ipMonitoringWindow *= *\).*/\1$Monitoring_window/" $CONFIG_FILE
sed -c -i "s/\(ipBlockingWindow *= *\).*/\1$Blocking_window/" $CONFIG_FILE
```

I need to do ssh and edit the above param.conf file on a remote server to which I am doing ssh and also needs to execute few other commands in that ssh session. Currently, files are not getting modified with the above approach

Comment: You need to run the sed commands within the Expect session - as the script stands you are running them after the Expect session finishes, so you are back on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up ssh key authentication, then you don't need expect at all (and you won't hard-code your password in a plain text file)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

NodeIP="10.63.12.19"
CONFIG_FILE="/etc/main/params.conf"
User_val=10
IP_val=5
Blocking_max=2
Monitoring_max=2

ssh root@$NodeIP << end_commands
  sed -c -i "s/\\(userMaxFailAttempts *= *\\).*/\\1$User_max/"           "$CONFIG_FILE"
  sed -c -i "s/\\(userMonitoringWindow *= *\\).*/\\1$Monitoring_window/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
  sed -c -i "s/\\(userBlockingWindow *= *\\).*/\\1$Blocking_window/"     "$CONFIG_FILE"
  sed -c -i "s/\\(ipMaxFailAttempts *= *\\).*/\\1$IP_max/"               "$CONFIG_FILE"
  sed -c -i "s/\\(ipMonitoringWindow *= *\\).*/\\1$Monitoring_window/"   "$CONFIG_FILE"
  sed -c -i "s/\\(ipBlockingWindow *= *\\).*/\\1$Blocking_window/"       "$CONFIG_FILE"
end_commands
```

You need to double the backslashes, because the shell is taking one round of substitutions before sending the commands to the remote host.

Comment: Where it is accepting the password? the problem is this script should ssh with the valid password and then perform the specific operations

Comment: If possible, don't use expect to login. Storing the password in a plain text file (and *root*'s password of all users!) is horrible. Generate an ssh key on your local machine with [`ssh-keygen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) and then transfer the public key to the remote machine with [`ssh-copy-id root@$NodeIP`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh-copy-id.1.html).